# Adult/erotic fiction about Ogopogo?

Tags: story-identification

Story set around Lake Okanagan in Canada. Protagonist is a biologist investigating Ogopogo sightings. She meets a hot hunk and steamy prose ensues. The mystery of Ogopogo is solved and everyone lives happily ever after (including the lake monster.) It was a short story, published for e-books, around 2007. I think the author has gone on to become quite famous as romance-writer since.

Comment: Sounds a little like Christopher Moore's [*The Lust Lizard of Melancholy Cove.*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33458.The_Lust_Lizard_of_Melancholy_Cove)

Comment: Can you add more details please?

Comment: The Lust Lizard of Melancholy Cove sure was a fun read!  This story though is very definitely about Ogopogo and takes place in the Okanagan valley in British Columbia. 

I seem to think that the author is (now) a relatively famous romance writer.  This story would have been written before she got famous.

Comment: One of the questions in the story is "how come there's only ever ONE Ogopogo?  Surely there has to be a breeding population for the species to propagate itself!"  The riddle to the question is answered in the story (very tricky life cycle of Ogopogos, dontcha know!)  When the life cycle of the lake monster is figured out, the Canadian government declares Ogopogo a critically endangered species and shuts down development and motorized water-craft on the lake.

Comment: It's not the story you're looking for, but James Alan Gardner's short-short story [*All The Cool Monsters At Once*](http://www.thinkage.ca/~jim/monsters.htm) begins with the Ogopogo lake monster.